# Find the completion of download in QWebEngineDownloadItem with the function isFinished() or finished() in Python

Tags: python, download, pyqt5, qtwebengine

I want to detect the completion of download by `PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineDownloadItem`.

I have read the docs but its showing error. I want to detect by `isFinished()` or `finished()` with this code below:

```
def downloadRequested(item): #QWebEngineDownloadItem
            print('downloading to', item.path())
            item.accept()
            words = ["The file was downloaded succesfully in", item.path()]
            sentence = ' '.join(words)
            print(sentence)
```

And the connect function

```
w.page().profile().downloadRequested.connect(downloadRequested)
```

Ok `w` is the view

```
w = self.QWebEngineView
```

I want to detect it inside `downloadRequested()` and after the detection I want to execute this code :

```
call(["python", "download.py"])
```

Comment: What error? Also, please provide a [mre].

Comment: You have to connect the QWebEngineDownloadItem finished signal to a slot that will be invoked when the download is finished as shown in the duplicate.